# Detect server/site support for cross-domain XMLHttpRequests?

Tags: javascript, exception, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain, cors

I am interested in seeing what minimal cross-browser Javascript code (jQuery is fine too) might be possible for verifying whether a site I wish to send cross-domain AJAX requests has support for [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

I know jQuery has a method to check whether **the browser** supports it. But I'd really like to be able to check if **the remote site** also supports it.

I thought I just had to check for a HTTP header but of course the XHR will throw an exception when trying to do a cross-domain request to a site which doesn't specifically support it.

But is there a way to check that an exception thrown by `XMLHttpRequest` was due to the site not supporting `CORS` rather than something else going wrong? (It doesn't have to support XDomainRequest.)

In any case I'm not sure the best minimal/fastest cross-browser way to to fetch an `HTTP HEAD` using AJAX, which I assume is the lightweight way rather than fetching a page, etc.

Use case: Once I know whether the browser and AJAX provider support `CORS` or not, I can choose whether to send the more featureful `JSON`/`CORS` requests or fall back to `JSONP` requests when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-cross-origin-request), it's not possible.

> If there is a network error: In case of DNS errors, TLS negotiation
>   failure, or other type of network errors, apply the network error
>   steps. Do not request any kind of end user interaction...
>
> Otherwise: Perform a resource sharing check. If it returns fail, apply the network error steps...

There is no special way to identify the case in which CORS is not allowed, since the [network error steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#network-error-steps) are applied in any case.