# Redirect web-page when no connectiontion could be made

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a small web based digital signage system. An Internet browser shows a series of pages in a loop. This must *never* break down, even if the destination page fails og if the Internet connection fails.

I need a way on In the browser to detect this and temporarily go into some kind of loop until the destination page is up and in the mean time show a default "logo" page that is generated locally in the browser so that the browser can:

1. Recover loss of internet connection (how to detect this)
2. Server side errors
3. Quickly resume when connection is up (how to do this)
4. Display client side generated "error" page

Is there a clever way of doing all this in JavaScript or is there any other solution? (im thinking that if no internet connection is available then server side scripts is irellevant, except for the server side errors)

The system is made using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670875/can-i-test-if-url-is-reachable-using-ajax-cross-domain-jsonp

Comment: I'm thinking that one way or another, **all** your loads must be through javascript. Or, if loading a linked static resource (say, an image), use some javascript "checking". A hyperlink to the "next" page could be adapted to dynamically load the content - fetch the HTML, replace *most* of the DOM, and probably set a hash URL. Feasible?