# How can I check if I can connect to a URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, connection

How can I check if I have a connection with a URL? Could be something like trying to download a image, something like if the server is online. Would it be possible using `javascript` to do something like this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? if so: show us what you've done

Comment: Use a timeout on a GET request http://stackoverflow.com/a/9670949/735204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you would need to use Ajax to hit the URL. If you don't get an error like 404 in the response then you have access to the URL.

Comment: The JavaScript tag description: _"f a library or framework is used, then tag the question with the appropriate tags[...] However, if a framework is not used or necessary, do not include these tags."_, please don't post jQ answers if no jQ tag is provided

Comment: according to Elias you should ignore the jquery example.

Comment: im trying to do this and check my localhost connection, it seems that is never online. Giving the error return always..